# how to access joining table/object of django many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class InvestmentChoice(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Offering(models.Model):  
    entity = models.OneToOneField(Entity) 
    investment = models.ManyToManyField(InvestmentChoice, blank=True)
```

The join table created has the following fields:

```
id | offering_id | investment_choice_id
1  |     277     | 5
```

I want to get a list of the Entity objects that have a certain investment choice.  I think this would mean I need access to the many-to-many joining table.

For example, if I wanted all the entities with Offering investment_choice_id of 5.

If so, how can I do this with a django query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the Offering entities with investment 5, the following query does the work.

```
Offering.objects.filter(investment__id=5)
```

If you want to get all the Offerings with some investment entities, use `in`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
investments = Investment.objects.filter(Q(id=1) || Q(id=5))
Offering.objects.filter(investment__in=investments)
```

For more about many-to-many query, you can check the [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and for making queries [read this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in two steps:

```
choice = InvestmentChoice.objects.get(pk=5)
```

Then I'm able to get all of the offering objects associated like:

```
offerings = choice.offering_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/, you could add something like the following to the InvestmentChoice model:

`entities = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, through='Offering')`

Hope that helps!